# Looking for the logical equation from this PMOS circuit

Tags: transistors, cmos, boolean-algebra, pmos

I am looking for the logical equation that describes the given circuit below.

Unfortunately I don't have information whether \$U_b\$ is positive or negative - would that make a difference?

[image: Circuit]

I derived my current result from a truth table I created.

\$f(a,b,c)=\bar{a}*\bar{bc}\$

[image: Truth Table]

I think, my logical term might be right, but I would like to know whether this would also be possible by just looking at the circuit and identifying NAND and NOR constellations in PMOS there.

Comment: Do you think parallel is OR and series is AND? and obviously polarity of Vcc matters.

Comment: I learned that parallel PMOS is NAND and series is NOR, but using that I can't come to senseful results. Is it possible to derive the Vcc polarity from 'the arrows of the transistors'?

Comment: Nobody uses Pch FETs like this with -Vdd ( but may exist) and Parallel is OR inverting so NOR. It is just an academic question.

Comment: Negative Vdd was only used for ECL. and not CMOS or even Pch FETs so this question is kind of useless.

Comment: This is not really helping, I don't even know what you're talking about. This was one of the exercises that was chosen in a previous exam and I have issues solving it. That's it.

Comment: Given no rules for Voltage and what is Logic "0' if Vgs=Ub then switch closes . so if both c and b Vgs=Ub then output is gnd (0V) so the  series a & b switches perform as  NAND since output voltage .is opposite to input. So your assumption that parallel PMOS is NAND or OR with inverted inputs,  assumed that 0V was a logic "1" using de Morgan's Law while convention is 0V="0" So it depends on your assumptions for Logic levels.  So polarity AND definition of logic levels does matter. Never assume unless you have to then specify assumptions.  ( I think it was a trick question. )

Answer (score 0):

Since you have connected gate of the PMOS to \$U_b\$, this voltage should be negative for the current to flow.
 It seems to me some kind of a ratioed logic, so I believe whenever the lower transistors are OFF we will get a logical one.
This happens for:
$$f = a + bc$$